# Search creteria for query in mailbox imap_tools library

Tags: python, email, imap

im trying to query in mailbox with python3 [imap_tools](https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/), cant uderstand how to extract emails with sender email and unseen flag. Trying like this

```
for msg in [msg for msg in mailbox.fetch(Q(from_=sender, seen=False))]
```

And always get same error

```
imap_tools.utils.UnexpectedCommandStatusError: Response status for command "box.search" == "NO", "OK" expected, data: [b'[CANNOT] Unsupported search criterion: FROM "ZOYA1608@YANDEX.RU" UNSEEN']
```

Can somebody explain where my mistake,
full code below

```
    with open("..\\conf\\conf.yaml", mode="r") as stream:
        for conf in yaml.safe_load_all(stream):
            with MailBox(conf['host']).login(conf['mailbox'], conf['password']) as mailbox:
                for sender in conf['senders']['from']:
                    for msg in [msg for msg in mailbox.fetch(Q(from_=sender, seen=False))]:
                        for att in msg.attachments:
                            with open(get_path(file_name=att.filename, store_paths=conf['store_paths']), 'w+b') as f:
                                f.write(att.payload)
```

Comment: Looks like your server doesn't fully support the IMAP search specification.  Try the searched separately to see if they work on their own.

Comment: got this error when quering with only from passed
    imap_tools.utils.UnexpectedCommandStatusError: Response status for command "box.search" == "NO", "OK" expected, data: [b'[CANNOT] Unsupported search criterion: FROM "ZOYA1608@YANDEX.RU"']

Comment: when i pass seen=False flag, query works fine, but i got all messages with unseen flag

Comment: Looks like the yandex server doesn't support From queries.  You'll have to do something else.  (Like locally download the envelope data and cache it and search that).

Comment: i tried to get messages from folder, they have filtered messages by rule, and there use unseen flag. In this variant i got attachments. But if somebody delete folder. the programm will stop working. So to protect programm from this prolem i solved use from flag instead inner folder searching

Comment: yandex.ru does not appear to support from searches.  It will work on most other IMAP servers.

Answer (score 0):

1. yandex server support From queries
2. A(from_="ZOYA1608@YANDEX.RU", seen=False) works, I checked
3. Do not forget update lib sometimes

Most likely: your server doesn't fully support the IMAP search specification.

Regards, imap_tools author.